# JRuby can not create a JFrame anymore: Java does not find WGJPI

Tags: java, swing, jruby

My environment is Windows 10, JRuby, and Java 1.8.

Running the JRuby program

```
java_import javax.swing.JFrame; 
JFrame.new("abc")
```

(which is actually part of the jirb_swing script that comes with JRuby) now results in an error

*java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: com.evidian.wg.jpi.WGJPI*

I am not aware that I have changed something in my Java/JRuby configuration, although our centrally managed Windows 10 might have been updated overnight. In any case, the code has worked so far without error.

I have found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/644) link to a similar problem, but it refers to WSL, and I don't use WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED the case by installing a fresh copy of Java (for the safe side, I installed all of the SDK, and not just the Java runtime) in addition to the existing one (i.e. I did not make an uninstall), and I made sure that the JDK's `bin` directory is first in the PATH. I also set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to this directory (it was unset before). After doing this, the error seems to be gone.